How to Enable Keyboard Navigation in a Non-Focusable JPopupMenu in Java Swing?
I am working with a JPopupMenu in Java Swing and need to allow users to navigate through the menu using the up/down arrow keys. However, I am setting the JPopupMenu to be non-focusable (popupMenu.setFocusable(false)) to prevent it from receiving focus itself.
When the JPopupMenu is non-focusable, I am unable to capture keyboard events (like up/down arrow keys) to navigate between the JMenuItems. The up/down keys don't seem to work, and I can only interact with the menu using the mouse.
How can I enable keyboard navigation for a JPopupMenu that is non-focusable? Specifically, how can I allow up/down arrow key navigation and selection (with Enter) for menu items in a JPopupMenu without making the entire menu focusable?
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PopupMenuExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("PopupMenu Example");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);

            // Create a right-click menu (JPopupMenu)
            JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Option 1");
            JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Option 2");
            JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Option 3");

            popupMenu.add(menuItem1);
            popupMenu.add(menuItem2);
            popupMenu.add(menuItem3);

            
            popupMenu.setFocusable(false);

            // Add action listeners to menu items for demonstration
            menuItem1.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Option 1 selected"));
            menuItem2.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Option 2 selected"));
            menuItem3.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Option 3 selected"));

            // Mouse listener to show the popup menu on right-click
            frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        popupMenu.show(frame, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        popupMenu.show(frame, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }
            });

            // Register keyboard actions on each menu item
            KeyStroke downKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false);
            KeyStroke upKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false);

            // Register keyboard actions for the menu items
            menuItem1.registerKeyboardAction(e -> navigateMenu(popupMenu, 1), downKey, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
            menuItem2.registerKeyboardAction(e -> navigateMenu(popupMenu, 1), downKey, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
            menuItem3.registerKeyboardAction(e -> navigateMenu(popupMenu, 1), downKey, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

            menuItem1.registerKeyboardAction(e -> navigateMenu(popupMenu, -1), upKey, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
            menuItem2.registerKeyboardAction(e -> navigateMenu(popupMenu, -1), upKey, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
            menuItem3.registerKeyboardAction(e -> navigateMenu(popupMenu, -1), upKey, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);

            // Open the menu and focus the first item
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                popupMenu.show(frame, 100, 100);
                menuItem1.requestFocusInWindow(); 
            });

            frame.setFocusable(true); 
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Method to navigate through the menu items
    private static void navigateMenu(JPopupMenu popupMenu, int direction) {
        Component[] components = popupMenu.getComponents();
        JMenuItem focusedItem = null;

        // Find the currently focused menu item
        for (Component component : components) {
            if (component instanceof JMenuItem && component.isFocusOwner()) {
                focusedItem = (JMenuItem) component;
                break;
            }
        }

        // If a focused item is found, move focus up or down
        if (focusedItem != null) {
            int currentIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
                if (components[i] == focusedItem) {
                    currentIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (currentIndex != -1) {
                // Calculate the next index based on the direction
                int nextIndex = (currentIndex + direction + components.length) % components.length;
                JMenuItem nextItem = (JMenuItem) components[nextIndex];
                nextItem.requestFocusInWindow(); // This will give focus to the next item
            }
        }
    }
}



The ability to receive keyboard events is the definition of being focusable.  Why do you not want your menu items to be focusable?

I am trying to make an ide editor

To make your JPopupMenu truly unfocusable, you need to make sure focus never leaves your parent JFrame.  To do that, tell Swing you want the JPopupMenu to be displayed in a separate Window every time:
popupMenu.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

Then, set that new window to be unfocusable:
popupMenu.addHierarchyListener(e -> {
    long flags = e.getChangeFlags();
    if ((flags & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0 &&
        popupMenu.isDisplayable()) {

        Window window = (Window) popupMenu.getTopLevelAncestor();
        window.setFocusableWindowState(false);
    }
});

Don’t register keys on the menu items;  add the key bindings to your parent frame.  If the popup menu is not focusable, it won’t get any keystrokes at all.  WHEN_FOCUSED can never be true.
frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("down",
    new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            navigateMenu(popupMenu, 1);
        }
    });
frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("up",
    new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            navigateMenu(popupMenu, -1);
        }
    });

frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(downKey, "down");
frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(upKey, "up");

Finally, your navigateMenu method can be simplified:
private static void navigateMenu(JPopupMenu popupMenu, int direction) {
    MenuElement[] subElements = popupMenu.getSubElements();
    int count = subElements.length;

    int index = popupMenu.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    index += direction;

    while (index < 0) {
        index += count;
    }
    index %= count;

    popupMenu.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(index);

    // JPopupMenu won't show its selection when the mouse isn't hovered
    // over it, so we must force it to be shown.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (subElements[i] instanceof JMenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setArmed(i == index);
        }
    }
}

The whole program looks like this:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PopupMenuExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("PopupMenu Example");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400, 400);

            // Create a right-click menu (JPopupMenu)
            JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Option 1");
            JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Option 2");
            JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("Option 3");

            popupMenu.add(menuItem1);
            popupMenu.add(menuItem2);
            popupMenu.add(menuItem3);
            
            popupMenu.setFocusable(false);
            popupMenu.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
            popupMenu.addHierarchyListener(e -> {
                long flags = e.getChangeFlags();
                if ((flags & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0 &&
                    popupMenu.isDisplayable()) {

                    Window window = (Window) popupMenu.getTopLevelAncestor();
                    window.setFocusableWindowState(false);
                }
            });

            // Add action listeners to menu items for demonstration
            menuItem1.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Option 1 selected"));
            menuItem2.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Option 2 selected"));
            menuItem3.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Option 3 selected"));

            // Mouse listener to show the popup menu on right-click
            frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        popupMenu.show(frame, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        popupMenu.show(frame, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }
            });

            // Register keyboard actions on each menu item
            KeyStroke downKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false);
            KeyStroke upKey = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false);

            frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("down",
                new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        navigateMenu(popupMenu, 1);
                    }
                });
            frame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("up",
                new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        navigateMenu(popupMenu, -1);
                    }
                });
            frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(downKey, "down");
            frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(upKey, "up");

            // Open the menu and focus the first item
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                popupMenu.show(frame, 100, 100);
                menuItem1.requestFocusInWindow(); 
            });

            frame.setFocusable(true); 
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Method to navigate through the menu items
    private static void navigateMenu(JPopupMenu popupMenu, int direction) {
        MenuElement[] subElements = popupMenu.getSubElements();
        int count = subElements.length;

        int index = popupMenu.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        index += direction;

        while (index < 0) {
            index += count;
        }
        index %= count;

        popupMenu.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(index);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (subElements[i] instanceof JMenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setArmed(i == index);
            }
        }
    }
}

